# How to Recover Lost Website/ blog data with no backup?

Tags: data

Unfortunately, our hosting provider experienced 100% data loss, so I've lost all content for my hosted blog website:

```
www.financewalk.com
```

Yes, I know I should have done complete offsite backups. Unfortunately, all my backups were on the server itself.

Can you please mention any solution/ tools that will help me recover my lost data?

Thanks,
Avadhut

Comment: Who is your host, please edit and update your question so we all know who not to host with.

Answer (score 2):

The website is still [cached and indexed in Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=site%3awww.financewalk.com&oq=site%3awww.financewalk.com&gs_l=hp.3...329.1590.0.1740.6.6.0.0.0.0.145.557.4j2.6.0....0...1c.1.27.hp..1.5.496.3bs2ToUMAKo) so in terms of front end content, if you're quick, you can still grab the content on your website's pages and use your browsers dev tools to get the site's source code and stylesheets (before Google starts dropping your pages from it's index).

Other than that, the only way of retrieving data is on the server itself and if your host can't do that for you then you're probably out of luck. It's incredibly poor for any hosting provider to not be able to recover any form of data - someone at the company must have made a royal cock up.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Geoff's suggestion, there is also a website called the Web Archive, which captures website and saves them.

You can view the cache of your website here:

http://web.archive.org/web/20130805135253/http://www.financewalk.com/

As Geoff mentioned this is useful for front end reconstruction, but of no use for back end/database recovery.